# Compare and trim name in Unix

Tags: unix, compare, trim

i have a problem with this part of script. I need to comprare two variable. Also i have set some function for trim that name that i need to compare.

Anyone can help me to find the error?

### Lock File Check

```
checkLock () 
{
 DATE_LCK=`date '+%Y%m%d'`
 FILE_LOCK=$DATE_LCK"_"LCK"_"$ENTITY".lock"
 cd $LOCK
 if [ -f "$FILE_LOCK" ]
  then
    for i in `ls -rt *.lock `
    do
      INPUTFILE=$i
      LOCK_ENTITY_NAME= `echo "$INPUTFILE"` 
      #LOCK_ENTITY_NAME= `echo "${INPUTFILE}" | head -n 1 | cut -d "_" -f3 | cut -d "." -f1`
      if [ $ENTITY == $LOCK_ENTITY_NAME ]
        then
          echo `date '+%a %b %d %H:%M:%S :'` "File Lock exist for the entity selected process interrupted" >> $LOG_FILE
          exit 1
        else   
        echo `date '+%a %b %d %H:%M:%S :'` "Create File lock for the Entity selected" >> $LOG_FILE
        touch $LOCK/$FILE_LOCK
      fi 
     done
  else
      echo `date '+%a %b %d %H:%M:%S :'` "Create File lock for the process" >> $LOG_FILE
      touch $LOCK/$FILE_LOCK
 fi 
}
```

Comment: What is not working here. How does you file name look? What is your expected value of `LOCK_ENTITY_NAME`?

Answer (score 0):

Test the vars with `if [ "$a" = "b" ]` (one equal sign).
Some more changes:

```
checkLock () 
{
   # Consider using lowercase vars
   DATE_LCK=$(date '+%Y%m%d')
   FILE_LOCK="${DATE_LCK}_LCK_${ENTITY}.lock"
   # Is ${LOCK} set to some value?
   cd ${LOCK}
   if [ -f "${FILE_LOCK}" ]; then
      # you do not need the ls
      for LOCK_ENTITY_NAME in *.lock; do
         if [ "${ENTITY}" = "${LOCK_ENTITY_NAME}" ]; then
            echo "$(date '+%a %b %d %H:%M:%S') : File Lock exist for the entity selected process interrupted" >> ${LOG_FILE}
            exit 1
         else   
            echo "$(date '+%a %b %d %H:%M:%S) : Create File lock for the Entity selected" >> ${LOG_FILE}
            # You already did "cd ${LOCK}", the touch doesn't need the path again,
            # you are still in the [ -f "${FILE_LOCK}" ] loop, the lockfile exists (you are only changing the modification date)
            touch ${FILE_LOCK}
         fi 
      done
   else
      echo "$(date '+%a %b %d %H:%M:%S) : Create File lock for the process" >> ${LOG_FILE}
      touch ${FILE_LOCK}
   fi 
}
```

With this code you can see more to improve. Now you are testing all files in the subdir, and you are trying to touch ${FILE_LOCK} for each file *.lock file.
You can do without the for-loop with `if [ -f "${ENTITY}" ]`.
Perhaps you want a logging function like

```
function mylog {
   echo "$(date '+%a %b %d %H:%M:%S') : $*" >> ${LOG_FILE}
}
# and call the function with
mylog "File Lock exist for the entity selected process interrupted"
```